# MS WORD 2010 Using VBA to type text into table cell then reformat and type more text w/o deleting previous text

Tags: vba, ms-word, word-2010

I am using this code which specifically places the text in the precise cell I want using this code:

```
    Dim myText1 As String
    Dim myText2 As String
    myText1 = "Header"
    myText2 = "Body"

    With ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Cell(2, 2).Range

   .Font.Name = "Times New Roman"
    .Font.Size = 12
   .Font.Bold = True
   .Font.Underline = True   
    .Text = myText1 & vbCr & vbCr & myText2
End With
```

The problem I am having is "myText2" is not supposed to be underlined or bold.

I have tried this:

```
    Dim myText1 As String
    Dim myText2 As String
    myText1 = "Header"
    myText2 = "Body"

    With ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Cell(2, 2).Range

   .Font.Name = "Times New Roman"
    .Font.Size = 12
   .Font.Bold = True
   .Font.Underline = True   
    .Text = myText1 & vbCr & vbCr
   .Font.Bold = False
   .Font.Underline = False  
    .Text = myText2

End With
```

But what happens is the first myText1 gets deleted and all I am left with is myText2.

and this

```
    With ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Cell(2, 2).Range
       .Font.Name = "Times New Roman"
.Font.Size = 12
.Font.Bold = True
.Font.Underline = True
.InsertAfter myText1 & vbCr & vbCr
.Font.Bold = False
.Font.Underline = False    
.InsertAfter myText2
```

While this appends the text, the formatting for the entire post is no underline or bold, when the end result is supposed to look like

**Header**

Body

How can I reformat myText2, have it post, without losing the formatted myText1 above?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your code you have set the `With` statement to work with the entire range of the cell. This results in the formatting being applied to the entire cell.

You don't have to use the `Selection` object to apply formatting, you just need to make sure that you are working with the correct range. Using the `Selection` object makes the code run more slowly as it moves the cursor around.

I have rewritten your code below.

```
Sub AddTextToCell()
    Dim myText1 As String
    Dim myText2 As String
    myText1 = "Header"
    myText2 = "Body"

    With ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Cell(2, 2).Range
        .Text = myText1 & vbCr & vbCr & myText2
        With .Font
            .Name = "Times New Roman"
            .Size = 12
            .Bold = False
            .Underline = False
        End With
        With .Paragraphs.First.Range.Font
            .Bold = True
            .Underline = True
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Nice one, seems like a much better solution!

Answer (score 1):

Normally it is better to enter text the way you do, without using `Select`, but when applying different formats to different parts of a cell I think you have to use it. I had to change the order of the formatting and step around a bit in the document to make it work:

```
    Dim myText1 As String
    Dim myText2 As String
    myText1 = "Header"
    myText2 = "Body"

    With ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Cell(2, 2).Range
        .Font.Name = "Times New Roman"
        .Font.Size = 12
        .Font.Bold = True
        .Font.Underline = True
        .Text = myText1 & vbCr & vbCr
    End With

    'Select the whole cell
    ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Cell(2, 2).Select

    'Move to the right
    Selection.Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseEnd
    'Move back to the left
    Selection.MoveLeft wdCharacter, 1

    'Add the text (using the myText1 format)
    Selection.Range.Text = myText2

    'Select the on word the right (myText2)
    Selection.MoveRight wdWord, 1, True

    'Format myText2
    Selection.Range.Font.Underline = False
    Selection.Range.Font.Bold = False
```

Comment: That is headed in the right direction, but the "Body" is a paragraph with several lines of text. Your code works to make sure the one word underneath the header is not bold or underlined, but for an entire paragraph, only the first word is plain text and the rest of the paragraph is bold and underlined.

Comment: OK - the line `Selection.MoveRight wdWord, 1, True` needs to be modified to account for all the text added. Is the amount of text known - is it always exactly one paragraph?

Comment: always 1 paragraph. I am using code to count how many words, and then inserting that variable like this: Selection.MoveRight wdWord, word_count, True. That works, but if there is a way to reference a paragraph, that would probably involve less code. I already tried Selection.MoveRight wdParagraph, 1, True but that reformats the entire cell to plain, including the header. That is why I went to a word count thing. Thank you for the reply.